# re-sync Gradle using Command line

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Im building script that will change some info in `gradle flavors` dynamic and then build apk Using `gradlew assemble' + $UsableProjectName + 'Release`

Now my problem is the new flavor i have added is not seen by `gradle` yet or in the project index files, so i need to click on `gradle` sync to be able to recognise it and run successful build.

I have tried :

```
gradlew --recompile-scripts
```

and

`gradlew assemble`

But after running both of them i still cant see the new flavor until i do manual sync from the android studio.

Is there away to sync the gradle using command line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shall work without doing gradle sync. 
do run command 'gradlew tasks' to see list of 'Build Tasks'; new flavor shall be listed as 'assembleflavor1' or 'assembleflavor2'.

Comment: you are right,  but when i run assembleTest_Full i get 

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processTest_FullDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'store.Test_Full' ,

and when i open build variants in android studio i dont see the new variant, any suggestions ?

Comment: You are right. I also see this issue. Why do you want to use 'android studio' when you also want to use command line. ? I have never faced this issue in non-android studio environment where i am running gradlew build command on linux machine.